# How to run a python cgi web server in windows

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, webserver, cgi

I'm wanting to run a very simply python based server in a windows environment, to test CGI scripts. I want to do this in windows, but run ultimately in a unix environment. So far, I have a simple server, and a simple program. When I go to the site, I am seeing a blank page, with nothing in the source, and I can't figure out what's going on.

Server

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

class Handler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

PORT = 8080

httpd = HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
httpd.serve_forever()
```

App:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgi, cgitb
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name))
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

I go to the program in my web browser, and I'm getting a downloadable output, with it being the name of the file. It appears the file has executed, but I'm not getting a valid web site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason not to use something simple like bottle?

Comment: @fp: Shear laziness. I just don't want to install something else for the moment...

Comment: Hi! I am attempting to do something like you are describing:

 > to run a very simply python based server in a windows environment, to test CGI scripts. I want to do this in windows

But I am new to CGI and webserver programming. I copied your code, in a folder I have to script, a server.py (server, and a test_CGHI.py (App). To test it I go to http://localhost:8080/, I can see the file in the folder and when I click on the app (test_CGI.py), I can see it is content but it is not executing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course I figured out the answer just as I posted it... I should just use a `\n\n`, not `\r\n\r\n`.

```
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
```