# get data from jquery client form into python server

Tags: jquery, python, browser

I wanna do a web-browser XML generator. Input will be as jQuery dynamic form and for server side (generating XML) I would use Python. How can I send jQuery form data into Python? Which framework should I use? I tried with web.py, but I could not make it done. I wanna keep things small and simple. Please help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Python CGI](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/cgi.html).
This question might help as well - [How to run a python cgi web server in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160709/how-to-run-a-python-cgi-web-server-in-windows?rq=1).